# Prevent simultaneous database updates in MySQL without locking the table

Tags: mysql

I have a multiplayer card game. Each game is played by 4 players. Each player is asigned a seat (1, 2, 3, 4), players click to join the game and when all 4 seats are filled the game can begin.

A game entry in the DB looks like:

```
id | status
13 | 3
```

The `status` is the number of filled seats. It is incremented every time a new player joins. Now I have a problem. Sometimes 2 players send a request simultaneously and they are both added to the same seat. In the example above, two requests are received and suddenly there are 5 players in the game, with 2 of them assigned to seat 4.

Obviously before I update, I check that there aren't already 4 players.

Something like:

```
if($row['status'] < 4){
    mysql_query("update games set status=status+1 where id=13");
}
```

Logically, this should prevent the `status` ever being more than 4, but if there are lots of players joining games, there's often a situation where `status` becomes 5 because multiple players join simultaneously.

I suppose I could prevent this by using table lock but I don't want to lock the whole table for the purpose of updating just one row (there could be 50 games in progress at the same time).

There's gotta be a reliable way to resolve this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could incorporate the constraint into the update statement itself, so that it is regulated in the DB:

```
update games set status = coalesce(status, 0) + 1 
where id=13
and coalesce(status, 0) < 4
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does that subquery do? Isn't this similar to just writing `update games set status=status+1 where id=13
and status < 4`?

Comment: @jovan: yes, you're quite right! Couldn't see the wood for the trees....I'll simplify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "select for update."

Something like:

```
sql:
begin(); // Need to be in a transaction.
select status from $YOUR_TABLE where $SOMETHING for update
code:
if(status<4)
   Set new status in database.
commit();
```

Select for update lock the row(Not the database, only the single row which match the where).

Comment: In this case, what happens when another request arrives while the row is locked? Is it turned down or put in a queue or...?